# Get all hashes from a list of keys

Tags: redis

I have created a list of `keys`: (projects) data ex: #, value project:1:1.

Those value from the list represents some hashes, `hash key: project:1:1, data ex: {id: 1, type: 'free'}`

With this structure can how can I get all the hashes in project:1 ?

Expected output:

`project:1:*`
`[{id: 1, type: 'free'}, {id: 2, type: 'paid'}]....`

Or how should I modify my structure so I can get my output?

Answer (score -1):

Either use 'KEYS project:1:*' to get all such keys and then iterate on them through GET, or better, Change the structure to use a hashtable, the hashtable name can be 'project:1'.

The keys inside can be an id with json value. Then use HGETALL.

http://redis.io/commands#hash